# Find rows where column matches one of n strings

Tags: mysql, performance, temporary-tables

I am trying to find the best way to see if multiple email addresses already exist in my database. I have a table with member id's, emails, and other info, and I need to import members but to check if members already exist. The amount of member that I will import will vary because it will be CSV files from users.

I dont want to make a really long "email LIKE  OR " ... etc.

I was thinking of making a temporary table and then union that table to my members table, but worried about performance. Any other ideas?

Additional Information:

I read in a lot of names and email addresses, and I need to check if those email addresses are already in the database. But instead of making numerous calls to the DB, or a really long where clause similar to "WHERE email LIKE '' OR email LIKE '' OR ...", I wanted to find a better way or getting emails that are either already in the database.

In the end, I did something like this for the where clause:

```
"email IN ('" . implode( "','", $inviteEmails ) . "')"
```

where `$inviteEmails` is an array of emails I am going to insert as users for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`,

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE email IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Comment: This works, for some reason when I was trying it previously it was not working. Do you know if making a temporary table would be more beneficial at a certain point?

Comment: Certainly if it has an index, and it's worth it

Comment: @Ice76 - Some people have reported issues using `IN` with huge numbers of values (like, thousands of values in a single `IN` clause). That's probably a case where it's worth creating the temporary table.

Comment: @RDFozz When absurdity strikes, SLEDGEHAMMER. ;)